# R Write in a txt File all column names that meet certain criteria

Tags: r, file, loops, matrix, text-mining

Let suppose I have the following data:

```
A
      1 2
term1 0 1
term2 2 3
```

I want a txt file like this one:

```
term1 2
term2 1 2
```

In other words, I write the rowname, and the column names in which the values are greater than 0.

I tried the following:

```
filename <- "palabra_documento/mapeo.txt"
fileConn<-file(filename)
rowNames <- rownames(AA.matrix)
for(i in 1:nrow(AA.matrix))
{
    line <- names(AA.matrix[i, AA.matrix[i, ] > 0])
    line <- c(rowNames[i], line, "\n")
    writeLines(paste(line, collapse = " "), fileConn)

}
close(fileConn)
```

However it does not work for two reasons:

1. Rewrites the file everytime (I can only put one line in the txt file, my mistake)
2. When there is only one column that meet the criteria, it is a scalar value, so, no names for its column.

Comment: Try `which(A>0, arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: Additionally, for problem 2, in the case where there is only one column, use the `drop` command inside your matrix to avoid a single column subset being coerced down to a scalar, like so: `m <- m[1, 2, drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(A <- matrix(c(0, 2, 1, 3), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c("term1", "term2"), 1:2)))
#       1 2
# term1 0 1
# term2 2 3
l <- apply(A, 1, function(x) which(x > 0, arr.ind=TRUE, useNames = FALSE))
sink("output.txt")
for (i in 1:length(l))
    cat(names(l[i]), paste(l[[i]], collapse = " "), "\n")
sink()

file.show("output.txt")
# term1 2 
# term2 1 2
```